# php require file path escaping

Tags: php, security

Now I'm wondering if is is safe to require files with only `require($path)`.

For *just simpliest example*:
I have some form field `folder` and `name`. So when I do `require($somepath.'/'.$folder.'/'.$name.'.php')` it can be easily relocated with inputing '../../admin/or/else/things/'.

It is simple example, but there are (i expect so) many other ways to relocate `$path`.

So the question is:
- provide checks of incoming path?
- if yes.. so how do it correctly?

Comment: require should only be used to bring in code from other PHP files. It does not seem to me that you should be passing in form field values to it (plus, just having a form field of the same name as your variable will not create a php variable). Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do?

Comment: You probably shouldn't allow a user to do that in the first place. If you do that, your application and even your server can be easily compromised.

Comment: @mtsvetkov so u want to say  that even if i'll require another file - i'll not able to do something to do whit it? sounds like a truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to require another file, based on user input, you should validate the folder and name fields **very carefully**. You don't want users to require their own files (maybe a file they just uploaded) or any other nasties.

Ideally, you should create a list of acceptable values, like so:

```
$allowedIncludes = array('a/foo.php', 'b/bar.php'); // etc
```

Then you can just check whether the combination of name and folder fields they provided is valid:

```
if(false !== array_search("$folder/$name", $allowedIncludes) {
  // OK
  // require ...;
} else {
  // not ok
}
```

But again, be **very careful** when allowing users to do things like this. You do **not** want to allow people to execute arbitrary code on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way:

```
/* Valid Pages' Array */
$pages['welcome']['title'] = 'Welcome!';                // Page Title
$pages['welcome']['path'] = './pages/welcome.php';      // Physical Valid Path
$pages['welcome']['login'] = false;                     // Log-in Required?

$pages['my-account']['title'] = 'My Account';
$pages['my-account']['path'] = './user/my_account.php';
$pages['my-account']['login'] = true;

/* Requested Page */
$page = !empty($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 'welcome';

/* Including ... */
if (file_exists($pages[$page]['path']))
    include($pages[$page]['path']);
else
    include($pages['404']['path']);
```